# A smooth manifold admits a nowhere vanishing n-form iff it is orientable

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, orientation

There is this well known theorem (the one in the title), I am reading a proof for it in Spivak's *A comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry*, and I have a question regarding a step in it. First, the definition of orientability  used in this book is the following:

> A Manifold $M$ is called orientable if there is a collection $\mu=\{\mu_p\}$ on each fibre $\pi^{-1}(p)$ of $TM$, such that for local trivialization $(t,U)$ with $t:\pi^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U\times \mathbb{R}^n$, where $\mathbb{R}^n$ is given a fixed orientation. Then $t$ is either orientation preserving or reversing on all fibres.

The proof of (non vanishing n-form $\Rightarrow $ $M$ is orientable) is pretty straightforward, the proof of the converse is the one I don't really get. We first endow $M$ of cover $\mathcal{O}$ which consist of local coordinate systems $(x,U)$ and a partition of unity $\{\phi_U \}_{U\in \mathcal{O}}$. For each $(x,U)$ we choose an n-form $\omega_U$ on $U$ such that for $v_1,\ldots, v_n\in T_pM$ for $p\in M$ we have $$\omega_U(v_1,\ldots, v_n)>0\Leftrightarrow [v_1,\ldots, v_n]=\mu_p $$.
We next define $$\omega=\sum_{U\in \mathcal{O}}\phi_U \omega_U$$
Then this almost immediately completes the proof since for each $p$, the sum is finite and always non-negative.

Ok, so my question is. Why is $\omega$ smooth? Does the partition of unity is really necessary? Why I mean by the latter is that it seems like we only needed $\mathcal{O}$ to be locally finite, we do not need the functions, we could just replaced them by the constant map $1$.

My idea of the construction of $\omega_U$ is that it should be defined by a given $(x,U)$ from which we generated the cover $\mathcal{O}$ $$\omega_U=dx^1\wedge \ldots \wedge dx^n $$ Here we may assume that $[x^1,\ldots, x^n]=\mu_p$, otherwise just re-arrange them. This is clearly non-zero in $U$. But how is the global definition of $\omega$ smooth?

Comment: You need partitions of unity, as always, to glue *locally defined* smooth objects to define a global object. $\omega_U$ is defined only on $U$.

Comment: And could’nt the functions be replaced by the characteristic function of the set. i.e. $\phi_U \to \chi_U$ Where this function is 1 on U and 0 elsewhere.

Comment: You'd end up something very discontinuous! Try it with functions!

Comment: Okay, great! I see this now. When I “glue” the “local forms” I may not get continuity. But how does the partition of unity provides this, let alone smoothness? Could you give some reference or maybe  elaborate on this?

Comment: I found the construction of bump functions and then partitions of unity,done from scratch, very readable in  in [Tu's book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441973993).

Comment: I have written other posts here about partitions of unity. Each $\phi_U$ is smooth and $0$ outside a compact subset of $U$. Before going any further, you should understand then why the product $\phi_U f_U$ is smooth for any smooth function, form ... $f_U$ defined on $U$.

Comment: This follows form finite sum of the product of pairs of smooth functions, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that $ \omega $ is smooth is that, near any given point, it's defined by a finite sum of smooth terms.  An infinite sum of smooth functions is not necessarily smooth; that's why $ \mathcal O $ must be locally finite.  And we need a partition of unity built from smooth bump functions, not just something like characteristic functions of a partition of the set of points, so that the $ \phi _ U $ will be smooth.  Of course, the $ \omega _ U $ are smooth since they are defined as a smooth function of the local coordinates and their differentials.

If I remember correctly, Spivak has a general discussion of partitions of unity some time before the discussion of orientation; check the index.  This should help reinforce the importance of local finiteness and smooth bump functions.  You'll want to understand this, because it's a trick that will be used over and over again to prove that something that exists locally can also exist globally.

By the way, you don't just need that each $ \omega _ U $ is nonzero on $ U $ but that $ \sum _ U \phi _ U \omega _ U $ is nonzero at every point.  Here it's important that each $ \omega _ U $ has the same orientation.  That's why, without the hypothesis that a global orientation exists, you still couldn't prove that a global nonzero $ n $-form exists.

Comment: Great, thanks! Yes, I got back there because of this. And yes, that las remark you made, I did notice it. Thanks.